# Can sklearn's pipeline be used for balancing and splitting dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been unable to find any tutorial, guide, or example code to perform dataset splitting and balancing as part of a sklearn pipeline.  Is this possible?

I have something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

### can this be part of the pipeline?
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \ 
    train_test_split(df, df['target'].values, stratify=df['target'].values, test_size=0.7, random_state=42) 
###:end can this be part of the pipeline?

pipeline = Pipeline([ 
  # is there a splitter or balancer class that can be added to the pipeline here?
  ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
  ('K Nearest Neighbor', KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)) 
]) 

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is it possible to have a pipeline like this instead?:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([ 
  ('balancer', Balancer()), # is there some magical Balancer() class somewhere?
  ('splitter', Splitter()), # is there some magical Splitter() class somewhere?
  ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
  ('K Nearest Neighbor', KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)) 
])
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Why do you want to put a splitter in a pipeline? Data splitting is supposed to be done once before the training. Or do you mean cross validation? sklearn has a cross_validate function that can split your data to, say 5 fold, during the training process.

Comment: I’m new to all of this so it was just a curiosity question. I do like the pipeline API. It seems more automatic. Those the cross_validate work with pipeline? If it’s something that is generally done outside of the pipeline then that’s what I would like to confirm as well. I didn’t want to just assume it based on example code. Thank you for your time and perspective 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

The purpose of `Pipeline` objects is to assemble a fixed sequence of several steps for processing the data and a final estimator.

However, `Pipeline` objects only transform the observed data, which is typically denoted by `X`. Transformations that also involve the target (typically denoted by `y`) cannot be part of a pipeline.

---

And picking up on the comments concerning cross-validation, a `Pipeline` is indeed meant to cross-validate the data processing steps together with an estimator, but not as part of the `Pipeline` object itself:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 


pipeline = Pipeline([ 
  ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
  ('K Nearest Neighbor', KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)) 
])

cv_results = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=3)
```

Comment: Wow thank you for confirming these things and providing the example code for cross validating.  That definitely helps point me in the right direction.  

Comment: have you ever used imlearn’s pipelines? https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html I’m curious what your thoughts on regarding their pipeline that seems to include balancing as part of their pipeline. I’m having a hard time understanding what are the boundaries of a pipeline. Imblearn’s pipelines do balancing but not splitting. It seems to me that balancing should be done before splitting and hence both steps should be part of the pipeline. Sorry I’m just confused on why splitting is never part of the pipeline but balancing can be.